# Does Gephi's scripting plugin accept hexadecimals instead of just "red" or "blue"?

Tags: scripting, jython, gephi

Code:

```
g.filter(join_month == "2008.03").nodes.color = red
```

Why doesn't the following work?

```
g.filter(join_month == "2008.03").nodes.color = #FFFFFF
```

Do I just have the format of the hexadecimal color wrong?

Comment: `#FFFFFF` is not a valid hexidecimal format in Python. Use `0xFFFFFF`

Comment: what's the output of just typing `red` in the console?

Comment: There's no output when I type `red`. It changes the color of the node in the graph to red.

This is what happens when I use `0xFFFFFF`:


`g.filter(join_month == "2008.03").nodes.color = 0xFFFFFF
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ClassCastException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.python.core.PySingleton cannot be cast to java.awt.Color`

Comment: @user1604416 It looks like the error is coming from Jython. I've attached an answer that should solve the problem. I don't have Gephi installed to test... if those answers don't work for you, please reply using @<my-username> at the start of your comment This alerts me to your response. (I did not see the previous response until I randomly revisited this question.)

Answer (score 0):

Gephi seems to be using [Jython](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) as the basis for its Python Interpreter.

You should be able to get your desired result by creating a `java.awt.Color` object and passing your hex value to the constructor, like so:

```
>>> from java.awt import Color
>>> mycolor = Color(0xFFFFFF)
>>> g.filter(join_month == "2008.03").nodes.color = mycolor
```

According to an example found [here](http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Scripting_Plugin#Applying_Filters) it looks like another way to do this is to use Gephi's `color` class.:

```
>>> red = 0xFF
>>> green = 0xFF
>>> blue = 0xFF
>>> g.filter(join_month == "2008.03").nodes.color = color(red, green, blue)
```